# Create a New Model (Polimorphic) based on some of the fields of another just created Model - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I'd like to make an enhancement of the code, that actually feels a mess.

When I create a User that has an 'email' field. I also need to create an Email model (Polymorphic) based on that same data.

Actually the UserController's "store" method looks a little big. So, is there another way of hooking the creation event, and then create the Email. Here is how I'm doing now:

```
$user = User::make($request->safe()->except('active', 'is_contact', 'groups', 'password'));
$user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
$user->active = (!empty($request->active)) ? 1 : 0;
$user->is_contact = (!empty($request->is_contact)) ? 1 : 0;
$user->save();

$this->saveEmail($user);
```

And the saveEmail:

```
private function saveEmail($user)
{
    $email = new Email;
    $email->fill([
        'email' => $user->email,
        'email_type' => 'primary',
        'main' => 1,
    ]);

    $user->emails()->save($email);
}
```

So, is there another way of doing this outside of the controller?
Thanks anyway. Hernán.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cleaner way to do this which is using the laravel observer.
you can do it in 2 ways:-

first way,adding creating function in the user model which will fire everytime a user is created

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot(); 
    //once created/inserted successfully this method fired, so I tested foo 
    static::created(function (User $user) {
       $email = new Email;
       $email->fill([
           'email' => $user->email,
           'email_type' => 'primary',
             'main' => 1,
       ]);
       $user->emails()->save($email);  
    });
}
```

second you can make in a seperate observer class see the link :-
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers

Comment: Great, it works perfect. One more question. I used the code you suggested. Can I use this same approach to watch for this same email field update? I'll need to update the corresponding Email model if the user updates the User->email. Thanks anyway. Best regards. Hernán.

Comment: yes sure you can use it for a couple of methods   [created-updated-deleted]